# Regular expression to remove all strings between two strings?

Tags: regex, bash, text, notepad++

I want to remove all strings between two other strings for all .txt files in a directory. How to do this?

Content of the .txt files:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr

[b]Download[/b]
[b][url=https://www.example.com]File.mp4[/url][/b]

[img]https://www.example.com/preview.jpg[/img]

Size: 640 MB | Resolution: 1280x720 | Runtime: 00:15:20 | Format: mp4

Tag1, Tag2, Tag3, Tag4, Tag5, Tag6, Tag7, Tag8

[b]Download[/b]
[b][url=https://www.example.com]File.mp4[/url][/b]
```

Now i want to get removed every thing between:

"Format: mp4" and [b]Download[/b]

So the final output should look like:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr

[b]Download[/b]
[b][url=https://www.example.com]File.mp4[/url][/b]

[img]https://www.example.com/preview.jpg[/img]

Size: 640 MB | Resolution: 1280x720 | Runtime: 00:15:20 | Format: mp4

[b]Download[/b]
[b][url=https://www.example.com]File.mp4[/url][/b]
```

Thanks for your kind help advance.

Comment: What to do if we have something like `[b]whatever[/b]` between `Format: mp4` and `[b]Download[/b]`

Answer (score 2):

For Notepad++:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

[image]

Make sure to mark Regular expression box.

The Regex we are using does the following:

```
(?<=Format: mp4)([^[]+)

(?<=Format: mp4)       - Starting after Format: mp4 (but not capturing)
([^[]+)                - Match all characters until [
```

And we are replacing that with two newline characters.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot bro.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak '/Format: mp4$/,/^\[b\]Download/{/Format: mp4$/!{/^\[b\]Download/!d}}' *.txt
```

the result corresponds exactly to your request, so one free line is missing above `[b]Download[/b]`